# Database where filter using compound index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, relational-database, database-indexes

I've a like object that can be used to keep likes to any other db table, each represented by a `content_type_id`

```
SELECT * 
from like LEFT OUTER JOIN "accounts_user" 
  ON ("like"."user_id" = "accounts_user"."id") 
WHERE ("like"."object_id" = %s AND "like"."content_type_id" = %s AND "like"."like" = %s)`
```

`like` is a Boolean field. What would be the best indices (indexes) for this database table?

Operations are, checking if a user liked an object, and checking which users liked which objects.

My current indices are

```
CREATE INDEX like_417f1b1d ON like USING btree (content_type_id)
CREATE INDEX like_e8701ad5 ON like USING btree (user_id)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX like_user_id_uniq ON like USING btree (user_id, content_type_id, object_id
```

)

And the query plan is:

`Query plan   -> Nested Loop Left Join (cost=26563.29..168218.18 rows=1 width=1383)
Query plan  -> Bitmap Heap Scan on like (cost=26562.86..168209.72 rows=1 width=29)
Query plan  Recheck Cond: ?
Query plan  Filter: ?
Query plan  -> Bitmap Index Scan on like_417f1b1d (cost=0.00..26562.86 rows=1271257 width=0)
Query plan  Index Cond: ?
Query plan  -> Index Scan using accounts_user_pkey on accounts_user (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=1354)
Query plan  Index Cond: ?`

Can you spot any irregularities? Because this is taking way longer than expected. (1.5 seconds)

I assume since the indices I have are not the exact WHERE clause this might cause a slowdown but DB engine should be smart enough to handle it, so that's why I am here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend

```
CREATE INDEX ON like(object_id);
```

This assumes that `object_id` is selective (there are many different `object_id`s in the table) and `content_type_id` and `like` are not selective.

If there are many different values for `content_type_id`, add it to the index.

If `like` is not evenly distributed (e.g. 99% of all values ate `TRUE`), it might also help to add it to the index.

I'd like to mention that posting a truncated execution plan like that does not help at all. We need the complete thing.